# Extensible Provisioning Protocol implementations?

Tags: python, c, perl, tcl

Do [EPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Provisioning_Protocol) client-side implementations for languages other than Java exist? I am mostly interested in a C or Tcl client implementation, but can also do with Python or Perl.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Tcl package that implements an EPP client at this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a Perl [Net::EPP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aEPP) package on CPAN that implements low-level and high-level EPP clients.

Answer (score 1):

http://epp-rtk.sourceforge.net/ provides implementation in Java and C++. (I believe this could be useful mostly to Google visitors.)

Answer (score 0):

> Do EPP client-side implementations for languages other than Java exist?

I have written [EppLib.NET](https://github.com/ademar/EppLib.NET); a .NET (C#) library. It should run OK on Linux via Mono although I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

Net::DRI is a full Perl high-level implementation of core EPP and dozens of extensions. It also provides a whois and DAS client. Available on CPAN or various forks on github.
Disclaimer: I'm its (proud) author.

Answer (score 0):

Recently published my EPP client library implementation in Python on GitHub:

https://github.com/datahaven-net/epp-python-client

It can be used directly as a client library.

Also you can run a local RPC server with a queue of requests and responses via RabbitMQ. Then you can use RPC client (also provided) to make calls to the target EPP system from any applicaiton.